# Actualización Parcial - PATCH

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas tengo un inconveniente realizo un Patch en mi Api con .net core y quiero que cuando se seleccione el campo UserPassword se actualice la contraseña sino que la deje como esta y no se como puedo definir una condición que controle eso si me puede ayudar se los agradecería.

```
        [HttpPatch("{userId}")]
        public ActionResult UpdatePartialUser(int userId, JsonPatchDocument<UsersForUpdate> 
        patchDocument)
       
        {
            var userFromRepo = _cruzRojaRepository.GetListId(userId);
            if(userFromRepo == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var userToPatch = _mapper.Map<UsersForUpdate>(userFromRepo);

            patchDocument.ApplyTo(userToPatch, ModelState);

            if (!TryValidateModel(userToPatch))
            {
                return ValidationProblem(ModelState);
            }
            
//Mi problema se encuentra acá no se que condición poner para que se realice la encriptación solo si se selecciona el campo UserPassword

            //Nuevamente se debea encriptar la contraseña ingresada
            userToPatch.UserPassword = Encrypt.GetSHA256(userToPatch.UserPassword);

            _mapper.Map(userToPatch, userFromRepo);

            _cruzRojaRepository.Update(userFromRepo);

            _cruzRojaRepository.save();

            return Ok();
        }
```

y esta es la clase donde se encuentra la función para encriptar contraseñas.

```
public class Encrypt
    {
   
        public static string GetSHA256(string str)
        {
            SHA256 sha256 = SHA256Managed.Create();
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] stream = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            stream = sha256.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(str));
            for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++) sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", stream[i]);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo pude resolver de esta manera espero que le sirva si alguien tiene la misma duda.

```
 string Pass = userToPatch.UserPassword;

            if(userFromRepo.UserPassword != Pass) { 
            //Nuevamente se debea encriptar la contraseña ingresada
            userToPatch.UserPassword = Encrypt.GetSHA256(userToPatch.UserPassword);
            }
```

Comment: A ver.. esto es un lio.. esto como soluciona el problema? o sea, solo te faltaba un if en todo tu codigo? no se entiende esta respuesta...